# How do I get the string value from Text?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a custom view that gets passed some Text objects. But I can't figure out how to get the string value out of them. For example:

```
let text = Text("hello")
// no way to get "hello" back
```

I've gone through the documentation, but for some reason the properties are not publicized.

Comment: If you need to extract the text from a view, this might be an indication of a bad design. Views should be driven by view models, so you should be passing the data - in this case, the Strings that you then supply to `Text` subviews

Comment: yeah ur right.. this is starting to feel pretty hacky lol

Comment: Just to expand on New Dev's point, you should be passing a String instead of a Text. Then, you can just create the Text inside your new view with the given String. Pass data instead of views.

Comment: Actually `Text`'s concerns are mixed, as it is not a simple view. Some SwiftUI views depend specifically on `Text` as a string value (e.g. `Picker`), not as a view. `Text` also supports concatenation for that reason. However when it comes to designing custom SwiftUI views, there's no official way of getting `Text`'s value. Which makes things overly complicated.

Answer (score 0):

in SwiftUI, you can use [`@State`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/state) to bind variables you want to change.

```swift
@State var value = "Test value"
```

and in the view:

```swift
Text(value)
```

Then you can normally

```
print(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of the context and if this helps with your particular scenario, but I came across your post as I had just been having trouble **testing** a `Text` value.

What I worked out for me, was I could use the *Text's* `verbatim` parameter to test the `String` (as below):

```
it("should show the content I'm after") {
  expect(viewModel.someText) == Text(verbatim: "some content I'm after")
}
```